# Is there a way to get the data from Dygraphs like plot.data in Plotly.js?

Tags: javascript, plot, dygraphs, plotly.js

In Plotly.js you can retrieve the data from the  element after plotting.

Is there a way to do the same thing with a Dygraphs plot?

```
Plotly.newPlot('id_of_the_div', data, layout);

...
var dataRetrievedLater = 'id_of_the_div'.data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the graph with

`var g = new Dygraph(....)`

The data is available through

`g.rawData_`